# KubernetesPodOperator is saying forbidden in composer for default namespace?

Tags: python, r, kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Helo I'm receiving the following error, and I don't understand why. I believe it has to do with the service account, but the service account should have editor permission

**Objective** Run an R script using the BashOperator, through the use of a Docker image which has R installed

**Error**

```
{kubernetes_pod.py:872} ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'metadata'
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'd338b499-5979-4d14-9ceb-e17b91dd7577', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'e2983b55-6f40-4b09-a2f5-6b07f7b3cd46', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'a1a2f4b4-f381-49a9-9edb-781b6cb62cdf', 'Date': 'Thu, 02 Nov 2023 23:42:04 GMT', 'Content-Length': '314'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:composer-1-20-12-airflow-2-4-3-a5161aba:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

**Code**

```
from airflow import models
#from airflow.contrib.kubernetes import secret
from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import os 

# Get current directory
cwd = os.getcwd()
#sudo apt-get install r-base-core

default_dag_args = {
    # Fecha inicial de corrida
    # https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 31),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'prueba-bash-gcs',
    default_args=default_dag_args,
    schedule_interval=None,  # Intervalo de corrida de DAG (periodicidad de corrida)
)


kubernetes_min_pod = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="test-bash-r-k",
    dag = dag,
    name="test-bash-r",
    cmds=["echo"],
    namespace="default",
    image="rpy2/base-ubuntu",
)

test_bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='test-bash-r',
    dag = dag,
    #bash_command = f'Rscript <URI to script>/prueba-bash.r'
    bash_command = 'Rscript -e \'a <- 3+3;cat(a, "\n")\''
    )

kubernetes_min_pod >> test_bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy workloads using the KubernetesPodOperator within Cloud Composer, you have to set the namespace to be `composer-user-workloads`. This is due to how GCP has set up the Airflow cluster (they have removed the ability for Airflow to deploy into the default namespace).

More information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/use-kubernetes-pod-operator). There is also a stackoverflow thread with this specific issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498599/how-to-set-proper-permissions-to-run-kubernetespodoperator-in-cloud-composer) that goes into more detail.